# trying to create a reveal animation with hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

hey guys so im trying to create a site and I have these 2 cards in the second section and what I want to do Is have then hidden until i hover over that specific area and to fade away again when i scroll or hover to a different part of the side but i cant figure out how to keep the 2 cards hidden and the fade away part i am able to reveal them with the hover css property on that specific section tag but i cant figure out the rest

this is the HTML as u can see the 2 divs here i want then to be revealed when i hover over this section only and fade out and stay hidden every where else

```
 <section class="cards">
    <div class="cards-container margin-top-1">
      <div class="cards-design-1 margin-right-10 margin-top-inner-elements cards-animation-1">1</div>
      <div class="cards-design-2 margin-right-10 margin-top-inner-elements cards-animation-2">2</div>


    </div>
```

and for the css of this section this is wat i have using keyframes at the bottom aswell. ps i am using sass instead of css and so just an indication.

```
.cards{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right, 
    rgba(1, 77, 113, 0.6),
    rgba(1, 77, 113, 0.6)), 
    url(../images/books.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: contain;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 5px;

    &-container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    &-design-1{
      height: 70vh;
      width: 40vw;
      background-color: $color-nav-blue;

  }

   &-design-2{
      height: 70vh;
      width: 40vw;
      background-color: $color-white;

    }

&:hover{
  .cards-animation-1{
  animation: slideleft 2s;
  }
}


&:hover{
  .cards-animation-2{
  animation: slideright 2s;
  }
}


 }
```

Comment: Have you created the slideright and slideleft keyframe animations?

Comment: yes those animations work fine but i cant figure how to stop the 2 divs from showing initially and when I hover somewhere else

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the divs to be hidden initially. I'd recommend against using keyframes as they're harder to maintain than transitions. Also transitions naturally give you a reverse animation.

```
    .cards{
    height: 100vh;
    background-image:linear-gradient(to right, 
    rgba(1, 77, 113, 0.6),
    rgba(1, 77, 113, 0.6)), 
    url(../images/books.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: contain;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 10px 20px 5px;

    &-container{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    &-design-1{
      height: 70vh;
      width: 40vw;
      background-color: $color-nav-blue;
   
  }

   &-design-2{
      height: 70vh;
      width: 40vw;
      background-color: $color-white;

    }
   &-design-1,
   &-design-2 {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s ease-out;`
   }

&:hover{
  .cards-animation-1, 
  .cards-animation-2 {
    opacity: 1; 
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in;
  }
}

}
```